# grep a file in perl script

Tags: regex, perl, grep

We use the below command to grep records in a file starting with a specific pattern:

```
user@domain>grep ^pattern file_name
```

now i want to implement the same inside a perl script and redirect the output to a file with minimal code(I dont mind using regex). can someone help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: `perl` supports pattern matching, as well as file based iterating and `grep`.  But as it stands, this question is almost too vague to answer well, because we don't actually know what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with something like

```
perl -ne '/^pattern/ && print' file_name >output_file
```

The -n option makes Perl process every line in a loop, so you don't need explicit loop code.

From there, develop on. You have to try and see what suits you best.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `P` switch in your grep command.

From **man grep**

> > -P, --perl-regexp
> >                   Interpret  PATTERN as a Perl regular expression.  This is highly
> >                   experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.

So your grep should be

```
grep -P "^pattern" filename >output
```